# How to check word part exist as contain without checking extract matching in JSON file using python

Tags: python, json

```py
import json

def word_exist_as_key(check):
   with open('most_used_common.json',encoding="utf8") as file:
      data = json.load(file)
      if check in data:
             return True
      return False
   
z=word_exist_as_key(str("අංගනය"))
print(z)
```

In here the word `"අංගනයක්"` exists but not  `"අංගනය"`. So I want to get `"True"` for this value.

Comment: Your function returns `True` if the word is found, which is usually what you'd want.  Are you saying you want `True` is the word is NOT found?

Comment: i think i get the question. he wants something like `has_key_with_prefix` for a dict, iiuc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

def word_exist_as_key(check):
   with open('most_used_common.json',encoding="utf8") as file:
      data = json.load(file)
      return any(True for _ in data if check in _)
```

Comment: `_` should only be used for variables you don't care about, e.g., when unpacking sequences.

Comment: @fsimonjetz this is a variable that is only part of the comprehension namespace so I don't care about it

Comment: I'd say `if check in _` counts as caring for the variable, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @fsimonjetz I respect your opinion but disagree. The var _ will not be reused outside of the one-liner comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest renaming the function to something like `prefix_exists_in_dict` or maybe `dict_has_key_prefix`, but in any case here's a simplistic approach you could take:

Loop over the keys in a dict, and if any key starts with a prefix, then immediately return True.

```py
from typing import Any

def word_exist_as_key(data_dict: dict[str, Any], prefix: str):
    for key in data_dict:
        if key.startswith(prefix):
            return True
    return False

assert word_exist_as_key({'අංගනයක්': 'blah'}, 'අංගනය')
```

As mentioned in comments, if you are not interested in checking if a key starts with a value, rather you want to see if a key *contains* a value at all, then it becomes much simpler. In the above code, you would simply remove `str.startswith` usage and just replace it with an `in` check:

```
if prefix in key:
```

Comment: I think this is a great approach if they're just interested in checking prefix. But what if they want to check any substring matching?

Comment: good point. I updated to mention how to best handle this alternate scenario as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would essentially need to iterate through all the keys to see if any matched. Word of warning, depending on use case this could be less than a stellar idea as keys must all be unique.

```
import re
import json

def word_exist_as_key(check):
   with open('most_used_common.json',encoding="utf8") as file:
      data = json.load(file)
      for key in data.keys():
          if re.search(check, key) is not None:
             return True
      return False
   
z=word_exist_as_key(str("අංගනය"))
```